# extend User Model in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
# this is models.py

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar/', null=True, blank=True)
password2 = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


# this is serializer.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('avatar',)

def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)

    profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
    return profile

# this is view.py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def User_view(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    user = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
elif request.method == "POST":
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(serializer)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'message': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response({'error': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am new in Django  I want to build a model to register a user with their profile image and password2 for password confirmation but I did not understand how to extend User model and give a proper message of success and error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom user model which will contain user data like username password for authentication and some custom fields like profile (in your case), you need to override Django's `AbstractUser` class.

`AbstractUser` class have attribute `objects` as `UserManager` which contains `create_user` method. This method handles the encryption of password.

Comment: def create_user(self, email, name, password=None): ...can i give  avatar parameter  also here  like def create_user(self, email, name, avatar, password=None) to register user

Comment: Yes.. you can....
There are like 2-3 steps to use your custom model as Auth model for django.